# map through array and return result

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image: results currently rendered]I am trying to print down the list of users who are using the server using map function in jsx. 
But i am not able to render and display the results.

In below code, i tried to map through sessions and return the list.

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderTableContent()}
            </div>
            );
    }

 renderTableContent() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul className="session__table">
                    {this.renderActiveSessionContent()}
                    {this.renderTableButton()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }                  
    renderActiveSessionContent() {
        if (this.state.activeSessions) {
            this.state.activeSessions.map((session) => {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <li className="sessionsharing__table__name">{session.UserName}</li>
                        <li className="sessionsharing__table__application">{session.DisplayName}</li>
                        <li className="sessionsharing__table__status">{session.Status}</li>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            );
        }
    }
    renderTableButton() {
        return(
            <div>
                <li className="session__table__button">
                    <input type="button" className="session__button" onClick={this.JoinButton.bind(this)} value = "Text" />
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

User               Application                  Status
User1              xyz                          active
User2              abc                          active

Comment: is this wrong method to render the list?

Comment: You do not `return` the result of the mapping

Comment: @VLAZ you mean i shouldnot return the results of mapping? can you show may be in my code how can i achieve it correctly?

Comment: `return this.state.activeSessions.map(/* ... */)` - without this you go over the array, construct a new one and do nothing with it.

Comment: @VLAZ below i have added the answer in this post and i hope you meant this to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return the results of `this.state.activeSessions.map(...`:

```js
renderActiveSessionContent() {
  if (this.state.activeSessions) {
    this.state.activeSessions.map((session) => {
      return(
        <div>
          <li className="sessionsharing__table__name">{session.UserName}</li>
          <li className="sessionsharing__table__application">{session.DisplayName}</li>
          <li className="sessionsharing__table__status">{session.Status}</li>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Additionally, when mapping an array you should set a unique `key` property on each iteration. For example:

```js
<div key={session.id}>
  <li className="session...
```

React should be complaining about it though ;) (You can use index if and only if the list of items is static and is never reordered such that the index in essence becomes the id of the given item)

Comment: below i have posted the answer and it works :) and i hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

```
 renderActiveSessionContent() {
        var sessionContent = [];
        if (this.state.activeSessions) {
            var sessionContentDetails = <div />;
            this.state.activeSessions.map((session) => {
                sessionContentDetails =
                    <div>
                        <li className="sessionsharing__table__name">{session.UserName}</li>
                        <li className="sessionsharing__table__application">{session.DisplayName}</li>
                        <li className="sessionsharing__table__status">{session.Status}</li>
                    </div>
                sessionContent.push(
                    { sessionContentDetails }
                );
            });
            return (
                <div>
                    {sessionContentDetails}
                </div>);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the object that you get from the map function , also whenever you use functions like map for markup, you should include the key attribute , so that react can differentiate between the same markups.

Ex:

```
renderActiveSessionContent() {
    if (this.state.activeSessions) {
        return this.state.activeSessions.map((session) => {
            return(
                <div key = {session.UserName}>
                    <li className="sessionsharing__table__name">{session.UserName}</li>
                    <li className="sessionsharing__table__application">{session.DisplayName}</li>
                    <li className="sessionsharing__table__status">{session.Status}</li>
                </div>
            );
        }
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```